# Inconsistent accessibility: Base class is less accessible than parent class

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Inconsistent accessibility: Base class is less accessible than parent class.
The error is coming on the base classes Circle and Oval. I think there is no issue of the curly brackets. How can I resolve?

```
namespace CheckingPolymor
    {
        class Shape
        {
            int width;
            int height;
            string color;

            public virtual void Draw()
            {

            }

        }

            public class Circle: Shape
            {
                public override void Draw()
                {
                    base.Draw();
                }
            }

            public class Oval: Shape
            {
                public override void Draw()
                {
                    base.Draw();
                }

            }                          
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: public or internal class Shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either

- make `Shape` `public`, or
- remove `public` from `Circle` and `Oval`

This error occurs because you are making access modifiers pointless. Without any access modifiers, `Shape` is `internal`, which is less accessible than its subclasses, which are `public`. By accessing a subclass, you can also access members declared in the superclass. This makes the `internal` `Shape` pointless.